# How to Validate ImageView where we are getting image from gallery

Tags: android, kotlin

I am sending getting an image from gallery in `imageview` and want to send this `imageview` along with `edittext` but when I left `imageview` empty and press the update button, the app crashes. How to validate my image view along with `edittext` android Kotlin here I have icons on my `actionbar` one is an update and the other is edit when I press edit my `edittext` becomes editable but when press update I have validation on `edittext` which will show "please enter.." but when I keep `edittext` unchanged and try to update my `imageview` cause problem and app crash

```
R.id.update_icon -> {


           email.setFocusable(false);
            name.setFocusable(false);
            phone.setFocusable(false);
            cameraIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);


       if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name.text.toString()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.text.toString())){
                name.error="Enter user name"
                phone.error="Enter Phone number"

        }
            else if(ImageUri==null || imageView.equals(null) || imageView.visibility==null|| imageView.drawable==null){

           imageView.setEnabled(false);
           Toast.makeText(this, "you have not choosed any profile picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

       }



            else{

                val formater = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss", Locale.getDefault())
                val now = Date()
                val filename = formater.format(now)
                val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images/$filename")

                storage.putFile(ImageUri).addOnSuccessListener {

                    imageView.setImageURI(null)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Sucessfully added data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }.addOnFailureListener() {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image uploading failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }


                Toast.makeText(this, "you have not choosed any profile picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

                val user = mapOf<String, String>(
                    "username" to name.text.toString(),
                    "phoennumber" to phone.text.toString()
                )

                database.child(name.text.toString()).updateChildren(user).addOnSuccessListener {

                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Sucessfully Updated ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()

                }.addOnFailureListener() {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }



            }


            return true

        }




        else -> onOptionsItemSelected(item)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're checking 
`if(imageView == null)` and then you're accessing it. Which may give a [NullPointerException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException).

Comment: i want a logic that how to handle app crash even my imageview is empty.. means i am sending edittext data and imageview in firebase but i want if i left imageview empty editttext update and app don't crash

Comment: @AndroidKotlin you need to post your crash log (the stacktrace, the whole thing) otherwise people can only guess at what the problem is

Comment: Agreed with @cactustictacs, We understand expected and actual behaviour of the application. But without looking at the log, we can't find the exact reason for the app to crash.
You can get more info at [link][https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/crash#reading_a_stack_trace].

Comment: That "if `imageView` is null, call a method on it" is definitely *a* problem though! But we don't know if that's what's causing the current crash. There's no reason to do that check though - either the `ImageView` exists (*not null*) but it's empty, or it doesn't exist (*is null*) so there's no need to disable it because it's not there